# Calculate $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} \binom{n}{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, summation, binomial-coefficients

Any input on how to solve this?

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} \binom{n}{k}$$

I have tried using Pascal's triangle but wasn't able to get anywhere.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} \binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \binom{n+2}{k+2}.$$

Comment: Try to integrate $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} y^k$ from $0$ to $x$ and then from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your work to solve the problem and also indicate where you stuck to get better response.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use integration on sums,however the hint from Gary was very useful (and the explanation from @Joshua Wang below so thank you guys)!Also I will try to include my work in next posts,I am on a pc so I could'nt scan easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{(k + 1)(k + 2)}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n!}{(k+2)!(n - k)!}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\frac{(n + 2)!}{(k + 2)!((n + 2) - (k + 2))!} = \frac{1}{(n + 1)(n + 2)}\binom{n + 2}{k + 2}$$

Notice that the part in front of the binomial coefficient is now *independent* of the summation variable, so you can pull it out of the summation.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes,I understand,thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

$$(1+x)^n= \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k$$
Integrate w.r.t. $x$
$$\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)}+C \implies C=\frac{1}{n+1}$$
Again integrate w.r.t. $x$ in $(0,1)$ to get
$$\frac{(1+x)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}|_{0}^{1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}+C$$
$$\implies \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{2^{n+2}-n-3}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Comment: +1 Great answer!

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation.